# How to simplify a repeatable pattern in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is that possible to simplify:

```
SELECT GREATEST(a,b)
FROM my_table 
WHERE GREATEST(a,b) > 25
```

to something like:

```
SELECT GREATEST(a,b) AS max_a_b 
FROM my_table 
WHERE max_a_b > 25
```

This try returns:

```
Unknown column 'max_a_b' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: You do know that you **cannot** use a aggregate function in a `where` clause, you'll need to use a `having` instead, and in a `having` clause you can use an alias :-)

Comment: Explain what makes having an alias simpler than having greatest(a,b) twice. I cannot see any simplification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT GREATEST(a,b) AS max_a_b 
FROM my_table 
HAVING max_a_b > 25
```

At where level your alias doesn't exist while it exists if you use having clause.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT max_a_b
FROM (SELECT GREATEST(a,b) AS max_a_b 
      FROM my_table)
WHERE max_a_b > 25
```

This should work, but it's questionable if this simplifies the query. 
Repeating the `GREATEST(a,b)` in the `WHERE` clause is fine, imo.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't run the `GREATEST(a,b)` twice, for what it's worth.

Answer (score -1):

The statement is still simple. And when your question is about optimization then this is better done by DBMS rather than you.